# Wpf TreeView With CheckBox

Tags: c#, wpf

I need to add "Select All" to my wpf application ,
I've tried to do a simple binding but it doesn't work .

Can Someone Please advise , performing a simple binding
or other strait forward solution ?

Here's my treeview xaml :

```
 <TreeView Name="CurrentTreeView" Margin="5" BorderBrush="Transparent" BorderThickness="0"
                      ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
                <TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="TreeViewItem">
                        <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsSelected}" />
                        <Setter Property="IsExpanded" Value="{Binding IsExpanded}" />
                        <Setter Property="HeaderTemplate" >
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">

                                        <CheckBox                                          
                                            Focusable="False" 
                                            Checked="CheckedItemCurreuntSession"
                                            Unchecked="UnCheckedItemCurreuntSession"
                                            Name="treeChk"
                                            Tag="{Binding Path=ChName}"  
                                            Style="{StaticResource CheckBoxStyle1}"
                                            IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsChecked}"
                                            VerticalAlignment="Center"/>

                                        <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding}" 
                                                   Margin="5"
                                                       TextOptions.TextFormattingMode="Display"
                                                       TextOptions.TextHintingMode="Auto"
                                                        />
                                    </StackPanel>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </Style>
                </TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
            </TreeView>
```

Comment: You should update all the child item as checked if parent item is selected. For select all, the only thing in that case, you need to select the root element. Check this -https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28306/Working-with-Checkboxes-in-the-WPF-TreeView

Answer (score 0):

```
<Style x:Key="CheckBoxListStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ListBox}">
    <Setter Property="SelectionMode" Value="Multiple"/>
    <Setter Property="ItemContainerStyle">
        <Setter.Value>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="2"/>
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
                            <CheckBox Focusable="False" IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent} }">
                                <ContentPresenter/>
                            </CheckBox>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response ,

Comment: unfortunately it wasn't so helpful since i read that post already.